# Set different theme for library project in android

Tags: android, styles, android-manifest, android-theme, android-library

In an android project which consists of a library project, I need to have a different theme set in manifest for main app and library. Like I need to set below theme in the main project

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/grey</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

and the one below for library project

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/red</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Library project styles are overridden by main app styles.
when I give different names for styles it throws manifest merger conflict error.

Below is the manifest of main app

```
<application
  android:name=".MyApp"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:supportsRtl="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

and this one is for library

```
<application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:supportsRtl="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  >
```

Comment: in your library you have some activity ?

Comment: Library project will have its own manifest. Apply library's them over there.

Comment: yes I have some activity in library project where the themes should be applied

Comment: @Wizard as I have mentioned library's manifest is overridden by main app theme

Comment: @arjun theme set on your library manifest `application` will be merged by builder, check the answer

Answer (score 21):

After building your app, gradle will merge your manifest files into one, so setting theme to `application` tag in library will be overridden by app's attributes.

Change your style name to a different name,

```
<style name="MyLibTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/red</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

If you are starting some activity in your library functions, then set the theme to activities individually in library manifest file.Theme set on `application` tag on your library manifest will be replaced on merge after project build, so set theme for individual activity

```
   <activity android:name=".MyLibActivity" android:theme="@style/MyLibTheme">
    </activity>
```

or you can use [setTheme](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTheme(int)) in your activity code.

```
setTheme(R.style.MyLibTheme);
```

On build process if the user (library user) is using your same theme name it will be replaced with main `app` module theme, to protect that situation you can use gradle option in your library's gradle file.

```
android{
  // replace mylib_ with name related to your library
  resourcePrefix 'mylib_'
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working in when I set this to activity in library project

Comment: you will need to set theme for the specific activity, not in your `application` theme you set in your library's android manifest, it will not work as i said earlier

Comment: setting the theme for individual activity worked but is there a way to set for the whole project in a library.

Comment: You can make use of fragments, Use a single activity with your theme, then use fragments or nested fragments for specific views

Comment: @IAmBatman, I have the same problem. In my case, the application is crashing. I got "Failed to resolve attribute at index".
One more thing is, If I do not use any custom attributes, theme gets applied to the activity and app is not crashing. Can anyone help me resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to use `tools:replace="android:theme"` under application node in the manifest of the main project. You can find the details and more here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge